# How to get the NAME(string) of the closest gameObject with tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my player float on top of the ground(dirt) in unity2D. For this i need to know the distance between player and the CLOSTEST dirt gameobject. I already got something, but i can't make it return the string name of the closets dirt gameobject.

```
float distance = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.y - 
GameObject.Find(FindClosestDirt()).transform.position.y;

public GameObject FindClosestDirt()
{
    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Dirt");
    GameObject closest = null;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos)
    {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance)
        {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    string closeDirtName = closest.ToString();
    return closeDirtName;
}
```

Unity is showing this error: 
*error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'string'*.
eventho i clearly return the *closest.ToString()*.
Did i overlook something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a GameObject not a string in the function definition. If you wanted it to return a string it should be `public string FindClosestDirt()`

However you already have the game object just return that from the function. This gets rid of the extra `Find` call.

You can also remove the `GameObject.Find("Player")` by getting its result during the Awake() function and saving it in a variable.

```
private GameObject player;

public void Awake()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("player")
}

public void Update()
{
    float distance = player.transform.position.y - FindClosestDirt().transform.position.y;
    //...
}

public GameObject FindClosestDirt()
{
    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Dirt");
    GameObject closest = null;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos)
    {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance)
        {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Another option which may be even faster is cast a ray downward and use the first Dirt it hits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name of a gameObject you would want to something like this.

```
float distance = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.y - 
GameObject.Find(FindClosestDirt()).transform.position.y;

public GameObject FindClosestDirt()
{
    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Dirt");
    GameObject closest = null;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos)
    {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance)
        {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    string closeDirtName = closest.name;
    return closeDirtName;
}
```

By the way are there multiple objects in your scene named dirt.
if not then you probably dont need the FindObject**s**WithTag and only need the FindObjectWithTag.